# Proving two quotient groups are not isomorphic as $\Bbb Q[x]$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have managed to prove that the following quotient groups are isomorphic as abelian groups, but I am struggling to prove that they are not isomorphic as $\Bbb Q[x]$-modules.

$M = \Bbb Q[x]/⟨x^2 + 1⟩$

$N= \Bbb Q[x]/⟨x^2 -1⟩.$

My main struggle is what should I consider as an operation for them to be modules?  Or should I just prove it for the natural operation (multiplication of the $\Bbb Q[x]$ polynomial ring?) and if so what happens when the operation is abstract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean... multiplying any element in $M$ by $x^2 + 1$ yields zero, whereas doing the same for $1 \in N$ yields $2 \neq 0$. Unless I am missing something, this proves they are not isomorphic as $Q[x]$ modules.

Comment: yes,but in this case the operation that makes M and N,Q[x]-modules is simply the usual multiplication of lets say the quotient rings.What i have trouble with is,what happens when the operation is abstract?can we still prove it?

Comment: define abstract

Comment: from Definition : An abelian group G is called a module over a ring R if there is an action(operation) * : GxM-->M that satisfies certain properties.
 Also an R-module isomorphism between two R-modules,lets say M,N is a group isomorphisms such that f(r*m)=r#f(m) ,where * and # are the operations of M,N.
 This is where i struggle,if in our case *,# is the usual multiplication i can understand what you say,but if they are abstract how?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your question is, can these modules be isomorphic as modules if we define scaling differently than usual such that they still follow the module axioms?

Comment: yes,that is where i struggle.

Comment: I mean, of course you can. The groud isomorphism induces one:

Suppose multiplication is defined normally on $M$, and let $f:M \rightarrow N$ be a group ispomorphism. Define scaling  on $N$ as $r \cdot n := f(r \cdot f^{-1}(n))$. $f$ will still preserve addition, and $f(r \cdot m) = r \cdot f(m)$ will hold by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Given any commutative ring $R$ and any two ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$, if $R/I$ and $R/J$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules, then one must have $I=\mathrm{Ann}(R/I)=\mathrm{Ann}(R/J)=J$.

So, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$ are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}[x]$-modules, as they have different annihilators.